# How to draw "gear" shape in wpf using GeometryDrawing

Tags: xaml

I am relatively new in WPF. How to draw "gear" shape using `GeometryDrawing` in XAML. For example:

```
<GeometryDrawing Brush="Gray"
                 Geometry="--coordinate--">
</GeometryDrawing>
```

or:

```
<GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
    <GeometryGroup>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="--start point--" IsClosed="True">
                <PolyLineSegment Points="--points--"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </GeometryGroup>
</GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
```

Shape which I need to get is display on the following picture: "gear".

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You may search the internet, e.g. for an SVG from here: https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=settings&style=outline

Comment: Thank you, but I should build that figure in xaml. I am interested how can make coordinates for that geometric shape..

Comment: What I mean is that you copy the SVG path data to your XAML.

Comment: I use syncfusion metro studio as my first choice for finding geometries. That has what looks like a suitable one as Gear_01-WF. It can also generate geometries from fonts. If I don't find anything there, I look for an image. These are often png or bmp. I take one of these and trace to path using inkscape, save as xaml. You'll find videos explain that tracing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need **exactly** the same result as the picture you attached, I'll just set the white background to transparency in some image editing software, and then used **Image** tag.

However, for my program I only needed black simple representation of a gear for button that opens up settings, and the best I could come up with is this, you still can edit it  if it does not match your needs:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <EllipseGeometry Center="5,5" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3"/>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 0,3.5 0,5.5 2,5.5 2,3.5"/>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 8,3.5 8,5.5 10,5.5 10,3.5"/>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 3.5,0 5.5,0 5.5,2 3.5,2"/>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 3.5,8 5.5,8 5.5,10 3.5,10"/>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 2,7 3,7.5 1.5,8.6 1,8 Z"/>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 6,3 8.5,1.4 9,2.1 8,3"/>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 6,7 8.5,9 9.2,8.3 7.5,6"/>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 2,3.5 1.1,1.7 1.7,1.2 4,3"/>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'll try anyway:

```
                    <Path Fill="DarkGreen">
                    <Path.Data>
                            <CombinedGeometry>
                                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                            <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                    <EllipseGeometry Center="20 20" RadiusX="16" RadiusY="16"/>
                                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                    <EllipseGeometry Center="20 20" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/> 
                                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                            </CombinedGeometry>
                                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <PathGeometry  Figures="M15.5 5 L16 0 L24 0 L24.5 5"/>
                                        <PathGeometry  Figures="M15.5 5 L16 0 L24 0 L24.5 5">
                                            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="45" CenterX="20" CenterY="20"/>
                                            </PathGeometry.Transform>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                        <PathGeometry  Figures="M15.5 5 L16 0 L24 0 L24.5 5">
                                            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterX="20" CenterY="20"/>
                                            </PathGeometry.Transform>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                        <PathGeometry  Figures="M15.5 5 L16 0 L24 0 L24.5 5">
                                            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterX="20" CenterY="20"/>
                                            </PathGeometry.Transform>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                        <PathGeometry  Figures="M15.5 5 L16 0 L24 0 L24.5 5">
                                            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="20" CenterY="20"/>
                                            </PathGeometry.Transform>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                        <PathGeometry  Figures="M15.5 5 L16 0 L24 0 L24.5 5">
                                            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="225" CenterX="20" CenterY="20"/>
                                            </PathGeometry.Transform>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                        <PathGeometry  Figures="M15.5 5 L16 0 L24 0 L24.5 5">
                                            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="270" CenterX="20" CenterY="20"/>
                                            </PathGeometry.Transform>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                        <PathGeometry  Figures="M15.5 5 L16 0 L24 0 L24.5 5">
                                            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="315" CenterX="20" CenterY="20"/>
                                            </PathGeometry.Transform>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                            </CombinedGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
```